# from host to another

Tags: magento2.3, database, hosting

i have magento 2.3

1. i restored databse and copy all file in directory of server 1   to    server 2
2. change the  name and  username and  password for database  from env.php
3. remove all file from  var/cache

after load frontend see [An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.]

this from exception.log

**[2020-10-27 18:20:05] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'u9794712_i5762828_mg2'@'localhost' (using password: YES) {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'u9794712_i5762828_mg2'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at /home/u9794712/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144, PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'u9794712_i5762828_mg2'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at /home/u9794712/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128)"} []**

how to solve this probleme

Comment: maybe your env.php file is not read, you may reset the site permissions

Comment: Is it necessary to use command line    php bin/magento setup:upgrade   and       php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f             after all 3 step